# Dates setting to default '1999-11-30'

Tags: php, mysql

My dates in mysql database are setting to 1999-11-30 no matter what I enter from my php form.

```
$degree_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$dt,$mo,$yr));
$other_degree_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$dty,$moy,$yry));
$expd_degree_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$dti,$moi,$yri));
```

Examples:

```
1. Date of Award
<select input name="dt" type="text" id="dt">
<select input name="mo" type="text" id="mo">
<select input name="yr" type="text" id="yr">
2. Date of Award
<select input name="dty" type="text" id="dty"> 
<select input name="moy" type="text" id="moy">
<select input name="yry" type="text" id="yry">
3. Date of Award
<select input name="dti" type="text" id="dti">
<select input name="moi" type="text" id="moi">
<select input name="yri" type="text" id="yri">
```

Insert statement:

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT into `acadmic`
`degree_date`,`other_degree_date`, `expd_degree_date` 
)
VALUES
'$degree_date', '$other_degree_date','$expd_degree_date',
```

I am getting messages that $dt $mo $yr etc aren't defined
Any help?

Comment: How are you storing/retrieving this data in MySQL? (We need to see the relevant INSERT/SELECTs, etc.)

Comment: Also how are you getting the data from the request, can you show that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A google search for "'1999-11-30'  mysql php" came up with a [non-bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45647) on the first hit to explain why "1999-11-30" could be your result:

```
There is no bug here, 00-00-00 means 2000-00-00, which is 1999-12-00, which is 1999-11-30. No bug, perfectly normal.
```

I tested `echo date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,0,0,0))` and that does print out `1999-11-30` as described in the reported PHP bug.

You may want to investigate whether your variables ($dt,$mo,$yr) actually have the correct values set from the form to begin with.

Comment: I am getting messages that $dt,$mo,$yr and the rest aren't defined. what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Since those are instance variables, unless they are explicitly set somewhere else in your script (directly or via import/require statements,) like `$dt = 9`, they are by default undefined as far as PHP is concerned.  Unless you are using a framework of some kind, you would usually fetch form parameters using either the $_POST OR $_GET globals (i.e. `$dt = $_POST['dt']`.)  It would help to show what your actual HTML forms are like and where there form is submitting to, in relation to your PHP script.

Comment: Might not be a bug but it certainly is non-intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using the

```
mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year, $is_dst)
```

function with the wrong parameters... You are passing `$day` in the place of `$month`.

```
$degree_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$dt,$mo,$yr));
```

should be

```
$degree_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$mo,$dt,$yr));
```

Check http://php.net/mktime

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$degree_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$mo,$dt,$yr));
$other_degree_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$moy,$dty,$yry));
$expd_degree_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$moi,$dti,$yri));
```

Refer this link